# How to add type to "this" in Vue 3 Method / Computed /

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I am new to Vue 3 and am struggeling to get the "this" typed.

Since we are integrating Vue in an existing app, the code looks something like this:

```
let app = Vue.createApp({
   data(): DataInterace {
      return {
         someData,
         someOtherData
      }
   },
   computed: {
      computedValue: function() {
         return this.someData + 1;
      }
   }
});
app.mount("#aContainer")
```

I have created an interface for my Data attribute, but I cant figure out how to (if possible) get code completion (aka types) in my methods. If I start to type `this.s` ,
"this" is type any and does not give me any intelliSense.